# Showing seats available based on Dates in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a personal project where I will be showing the number of seats available in a particular organization. Initially, I created a State with Organization names and seats available in them.

```
state = {
    hospitals: [
      { id: 1, status: false, name: 'Apollo Hospital', city: 'Chennai', bedtype1: 500, bedtype2: 800, bedtype3: 1300,bed1av: 60, bed2av: 40, bed3av: 20, },
      { id: 2, status:false, name: 'Fortis Hospital', city: 'New Delhi', bedtype1: 600, bedtype2: 1000, bedtype3: 1400, bed1av: 60, bed2av: 40, bed3av: 20,  },
      { id: 3, status: false, name: 'Tata Memorial Hospital', city: 'Mumbai', bedtype1: 400, bedtype2: 800, bedtype3: 1200, bed1av: 60, bed2av: 40, bed3av: 20,  },
      { id: 4, status: false,name: 'Lilavati Hospital', city: 'Pune', bedtype1: 500, bedtype2: 900, bedtype3: 1300, bed1av: 60, bed2av: 40, bed3av: 20,  }
    ],
};
```

I am required to show the seats available based on the dates someone choose from date picker. How can I go through this?

Comment: With only the data you've shown us you can't.

Comment: you need to integrate timestamp (Date/time) in your data.

Comment: How can I make the data dynamic instead of hard coding the dates. Even if i add upto 30 datas with particular dates.How can it be dynamically changed on the next day?

Comment: Where do you get your data from? Surely none of it is hard coded?!

Comment: The state i have posted is the only data  The additional data is that I have to store the same data with dates.